# Push Arrays' indexes into one object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, object

How to push array indexes into one object where the correspondence between `{key:value}` in my example would be `{authors[i]: quotes[i]}`?

Please check my codepen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ndezeo

Thanks.

Comment: please add the relevant code to the question. pleaas have a look here, too [mcve]

Comment: Haven't I posted the codepen??

Comment: @tholo The code must be *in the question itself* not on a third party site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could iterate `authors` and take the name as key and assign the item of `quotes` as property of the object.

```js
var quotes = [], 
    authors = [],
    object = {};

quotes[0] = "I have a new philosophy. I'm only going to dread one day at a time.";
authors[0] = "Charles Schulz";
quotes[1] = "Reality is the leading cause of stress for those in touch with it.";
authors[1] = "Jack Wagner";
quotes[2] = "Few things are harder to put up with than the annoyance of a good example.";
authors[2] = "Mark Twain";
quotes[3] = "The pure and simple truth is rarely pure and never simple.";
authors[3] = "Oscar Wilde";
quotes[4] = "There's no business like show business, but there are several businesses like accounting.";
authors[4] = "David Letterman";
quotes[5] = "Man invented language to satisfy his deep need to complain.";
authors[5] = "Lily Tomlin";

authors.forEach(function (k, i) {
    object[k] = quotes[i];
});

console.log(object);
```

Comment: Thanks Nina,  exactly what I needed. :)

Comment: @tholo But what happens if you quote the same person twice?

Comment: Nothing, this is just for the learning practice. Now, that you have mentioned it, how would you avoid that?

Comment: actually the last value stays.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question would be:

```
 var combined = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < quotes.length; i++) {
    combined[authors[i]] = quotes[i]
 }
 console.log(combined);
```

But the really simple and elegant solution here would be to place all your values in a single array from the start:

```
 var quotes = [
   {
     author: "Charles Schulz",
     quote: "I have a new philosophy. I'm only going to dread one day at a time."
   },
   {
     author:  "Jack Wagner",
     quote: "Reality is the leading cause of stress for those in touch with it."
   }
   /* etc... */
 ];
```

Than you can go over your `quotes` array with a simple for:

```
console.log(quotes);
for (var i = 0; i < quotes.length; i++) {
   /* access each object like this: 
   quotes[i].author;
   quotes[i].quote;
   */
}
```

Alternatively, depending on your needs you could structure your data in an object, with this structure:

```
quotes = {
  "Charles Schulz":"I have a new philosophy. I'm only going to dread one day at a time.",
  "Jack Wagner":"Reality is the leading cause of stress for those in touch with it."
  /* etc... */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `for...of` loop and **ES6** destructing or [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to build a new object.

```js
let quotes = [];
let authors = [];
let object = {};

quotes[0] = "I have a new philosophy. I'm only going to dread one day at a time.";
authors[0] = "Charles Schulz";
quotes[1] = "Reality is the leading cause of stress for those in touch with it.";
authors[1] = "Jack Wagner";
quotes[2] = "Few things are harder to put up with than the annoyance of a good example.";
authors[2] = "Mark Twain";
quotes[3] = "The pure and simple truth is rarely pure and never simple.";
authors[3] = "Oscar Wilde";
quotes[4] = "There's no business like show business, but there are several businesses like accounting.";
authors[4] = "David Letterman";
quotes[5] = "Man invented language to satisfy his deep need to complain.";
authors[5] = "Lily Tomlin";

// for...of loop taking advantage of the new array method entries & using destructuring
for (const [index, element] of authors.entries()) {
  if (!object[element])
object[element] = quotes[index];
}

console.log('Result of using for...of loop:', object);

// array method reduce: Setting an object as the initial value 
const usingReduce = authors.reduce((obj, author, index) => {
  if (!obj[author])
obj[author] = quotes[index];

  return obj; // always return initial value
}, {}); // here I set an obj as the initial value

console.log('Result of using Array#reduce: ', usingReduce);

 // using map to return an object containing the authors
 // { author: author } same key/value pairs can be shortened to ->  { author }
const usingMap = authors.map((author, index, authorsArray) => ({
  author,
  quote: quotes[index]
}));

console.log('Result of using Array#map method: ', usingMap);
```